# .htaccess with or without slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

What do I need to do to the following rewrite rule to make it so it works whether or not their is a slash at the end of the URL?

ie.
http://mydomain.com/content/featured
or
http://mydomain.com/content/featured/

```
RewriteRule ^content/featured/ /content/today.html
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use the `$` to mark the end of the string and the `?` to mark the preceding expression to be repeated zero or one times:

```
RewriteRule ^content/featured/?$ content/today.html
```

But I recommend you to stick to one notation and correct misspelled:

```
# remove trailing slashes
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

# add trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: +1 mostly for the additional info, although I was gonna' give it to you anyway.

Comment: @JensTörnell `$0` contains the whole matched string.

Answer (score 4):

simple way to do this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^content/featured(\/||)$ /content/today.html [L,R=301,NC]
```