# RewriteRule of .htaccess, with slash at the end

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two kinds of links on my site: first are finishing with .html, and second that are finishing with / (with slash, in a case that filename is not finishing with .html).

Cause of some rewriting rules, in a case that file is not .html, and if is added / at the end, URL is not properly rewritten.

Like:

It is ok with link: `http://mysite.com/cars/fast-cars`

But not ok with link: `http://mysite.com/cars/fast-cars/`

So, what I need is when URL is finishing with `/` and not with (`.html/`), to be redirected to same page, without `/`, or in this case:

`http://mysite.com/cars/fast-cars/` to be redirected to `http://mysite.com/cars/fast-cars`.

Hope I was clear, and that you can help me with that htaccess rule. Thank you in advance.

**UPDATED:** i did found part of solution here: [.htaccess with or without slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540493/htaccess-with-or-without-slash).

but, also, my rule should not be valid for some subdirectories (like directory admin, orders, etc). can it be defined also with same rule?

**UPDATE 2:** I have rules like:

```
RewriteRule ^cars/fast-cars$ /seopage.php?marker=fast-cars$1
```

Also, tryed with rule that works:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

But that rule have to be bypassed for some directories (ie. admin, orders, etc.).

Comment: Please show your rules that you have right now (including those that you have added recently). Preferably with comments.

Comment: What folders (name a few)? Are they real .. or they "virtual" as the `/cars/fast-cars` is? There should be no problem with adding such condition, I'm just trying to make it clear for myself.

Comment: folders are real. their names (at this moment are admin and orders, but there will be more in the future).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in few ways (choose the one that works best for you).

1) Remove trailing slash `/` for non-existing files and folders:

```
# remove trailing slash for non-existing files and folders
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

2) Remove trailing slash `/` with exceptions

```
# remove trailing slash except some folders
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(admin|orders)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

3) You can even combine it together (which can be too much):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(admin|orders)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Also, consider adding this directive somewhere at the top -- [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash):

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

Comment: I think that 2 will do the job. Does it works for subdirs of mentioned directories?

Comment: Yes, the condition says: "unless/except URLs **start** with `/admin` or `/orders`" which will apply to `/admin/dashboard/` etc as well.