# 301 Redirect not working as expected

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a strange `301 Redirect` problem.

I'm using the following rule

```
Redirect 301   /catalog/index.php?target=news /news
```

Oddly, when I visit `/catalog/index.php?target=news`

I'm redirected to : `/catalog/?target=news`

Comment: Try URL encoding the redirect URL - the / in "/news" could be causing some strange behavior.

Comment: hm... im not sure how to encode in htaccess - can you give me an example?

Comment: I think the last slash in your querystring value is what's throwing you off.  Try this - /catalog/index.php?target=news+%2Fnews

Comment: Ahh... no. Sorry. Here's a post that explains to add a $ to the end of the inbound value, to deliniate where the replacement starts:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540493/htaccess-with-or-without-slash. So try... /catalog/index.php?target=news$ /news

Answer (score 0):

The query string isn't part of the URI that the `Redirect` pattern is matched against. It's removed so you can't attempt to match against it in your statement. You need to use mod_rewrite and a condition that matches against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^target=news$
RewriteRule ^/?catalog/(index\.php)?$ /news? [L,R=301]
```

Those rules should go in the htaccess file in your document root.